# No easy way to show a PreferenceFragment in a new screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use PreferenceFragment instead of PreferenceActivity, since I don't like the use of the word "deprecated" in my code.

I've built my preferences layout and PreferenceFragment class all ok. Now I just have to launch it when the user clicks "settings" in the menu. Obviously I want them to be taken to a new page for this. With PreferenceActivity, this was easy - just call startActivity with the Intent.

With PreferenceFragment, I have to create a new Activity, then set the preference inside it. If I just do replace(android.R.id.content, fragment) in my current activity, the fragment overlays or overlaps with the current layout which is set in setContentView(). This seems like a hell of a lot of work just to show a simple settings fragment. If I'm going to create a new activity to hold the fragment, I might as well have gone with PreferenceActivity in the first place.

So am I missing something here? All I want to do is to show my pretty PreferenceFragment in a new screen. No easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make  the whole main layout a framelayout instead of hardcoding a fragment in.

That would let you swap fragments in and out without problem.

I've always thought that hardcoding a fragment in the XML went against the nature and purpose of fragments.

Comment: But that means in landscape mode I would have fragments within fragments...a little too messy :(